# Retrieving UID's from Firebase in ANgular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using simple email/password and google signin (firebase) login authentication in my Angular project. I want to retrieve User Id (UID) of the user who is currently logged in the product. Is there a way angular provides to retrieve the UID?

[image: Firebase Authentication data]

```js
this.authenticationService.SignUp(this.institutes.email,"123456");
    console.log(this.af.auth.currentUser.uid);
```

Authentication Script:

```js
SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
this.angularFireAuth
.auth
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(res => {
console.log('You are Successfully signed up!', res);
this.angularFireAuth
    .auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(res => {
    console.log('You are Successfully logged in!');
    return 1;
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log('Something is wrong:',err.message);
    });
})
.catch(error => {
console.log('Something is wrong:', error.message);
});
}
```

I have signed up a new account and logged in the user at the same time. I tried to retreive UID of the user after logging in, but I am receiving the folloing error:
Error:Object is possibly 'null'. 
Error is on line: console.log(this.af.auth.currentUser.uid);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve the uid, you can use AngularFire and do the following:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  getUid() {
    this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
  }
}
```

You can check here for more information:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md

Comment: Is it possible for us to manually pass an email id to get it's corresponding UID?

Answer (score 2):

Peter answered how to get the UID of the logged-in user when you use AngularFire2. If you're not using AngularFire (or even if you are), you can get the UID of the current user with:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
```

Comment: Is it possible for us to manually pass an email id to get it's corresponding UID?

Comment: Nope. That functionality is not available in the client-side SDK. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+look+up+uid+by+email

Comment: I have appended the code I tried to retrieve the UID but still failed to get it. Please go look into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can retrieve the user id at the end of 2021.

```
import { AngularFireAuth }           from "@angular/fire/auth";

constructor
   // paramenters
(
   public angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth

)
   // code block
{
}

this.angularFireAuth.currentUser.then( data  => {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.uid);
)}
```

package.json

```
"firebase": "^7.0 || ^8.0",
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5"
```